# How to forward specific domain queries to different dns server using dnsmasq?

Tags: networking, server, apache2, dns, dnsmasq

I want that all http requests on the browser be directed to my local apache server but direct some https queries like facebook.com to google's dns 8.8.8.8 using dnsmasq. I've already tried adding an entry like this one to my dnsmasq.conf:

```
server=/facebook.com/8.8.8.8
```

Also tried entering this in /etc/dnsmasq.d/custom-dns and still no help.

My dnsmasq.conf file looks like this:

```
interface=wlan0      # Use interface wlan0
server=/facebook.com/8.8.8.8
listen-address=192.168.1.1
bind-interfaces 
server=8.8.8.8
#domain-needed  
#bogus-priv           
dhcp-range=192.168.1.50,192.168.1.150,12h
address=/#/192.168.1.1
```

But this does not help and I am getting a **DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN** error. Where am I going wrong?